# Appending multiple values from textmining into a single list in python

Tags: python, csv, text-mining

I have a csv file that I am importing data from.  I am trying to create a list of words used in two essays and how many times they are used.  I am running a loop to get each line of the csv file which has two essays, and the output posts the combined word count between the two essays.  However, I hundreds of lines that have two essays each.  I would like for there to be one list with all words and word counts from all the essays.

```
import textmining

import csv

with open('2011ShortAnswers.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    data = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",")

    for row in data:
        doc1 = row[3]
        doc2 = row[4]

        tdm = textmining.TermDocumentMatrix()

        tdm.add_doc(doc1)
        tdm.add_doc(doc2)

        for row in tdm.rows(cutoff=1):
            print row
```

Comment: Could you give us a little sample of the csv file to work with?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a dictionary where you increment each word as you go:

```
word_count_dictionary = {}
for word in row:
    if word not in word_count_dictionary.keys():
        word_count_dictionary[word] = 1
    else:
        word_count_dictionary[word] += 1
```

You can then iterate over the keys to form the list you need:

```
word_count_list = [(word,word_count_dictionary[word]) for word in word_count_dictionary.keys()]
```